# User selection of certificate inside webview

Tags: flutter, webview, client-certificates, flutter-inappwebview

I need to load a login page in a webview so the user can authenticate by choosing a user certificate installed in his phone. Right now I'm using flutter_inappwebview, but I could use another plugin if needed.

When loading this page in Chrome, the user gets a system dialog to select the certificate they want to use. But no dialog pops up for the request when using the webview.

[image: certificate dialog]

`InAppWebView` has a `onReceivedClientCertRequest` callback, but the `ClientCertResponse` class expects a `certificatePath` as param. Do I need to create the dialog by myself and get a path as a result?

I tried adding a `networkSecurityConfig` trusting user certificates just in case, but it didn't work:

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">xxx</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Is this a feature that flutter_inappwebview or another webview implementation supports right now? Is this something that should work out of the box? Do I need to configure something, or ask for a certain permission?

Thank you for your help